# Filling an Excel Cell based on data in two other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ok, I'm going to try and explain this as best as I can.  I'm looking to fill a name field in Excel based on data in two other cells.  Basically if Tone 1 is A and Tone 2 B name = XYZ. I know I could do this with an IF statement, but Tone 1 and Tone 2 could be a bunch of different things.  I'm thinking there has to be a way to create a table elsewhere and ask the cell to check that table for a name.  Does this make sense?

[image: example]

Comment: You could probably do this with lookup tables

Comment: To create the lookup table use `UNIQUE()` on the data range of Tone 1 and Tone 2. Then in the 3rd column populate that with the names that you are associating to the  combinations.

Comment: how to get XYZ from A & B values? any example? | btw.. is [CONCAT()](https://exceljet.net/functions/concat-function) function suit it?

Comment: SUMPRODUCT function?